# Is it possible to click on a certain point in a webpage using Java?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am importing the following methods:

```
import helper.webdriver.ExtraMethods;
import helper.webdriver.JavascriptMethods;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

I need to click (or clickAndWait) on a span element which seems to be bigger than the CTA itself, without any child elements iside it (except for the text).

So, I would like to know if there is a way to have my IDE click on a certain point on a webpage (like if you enter coordinates, it will click on the corresponding location).

Alternatively, I would like to know if it is possible to directly click on the actual text (as the text is included in the CTA, and the command would validate).

Thank you in advance!

Later Edit:

The URL in which I am attempting this is http://www.chevrolet.com/current-deals

My problem is that I would like to click on the "Request a Quote" CTA for any vehicle (this appears after clicking on any "Offers" button). I went within the iframe but i tried clicking by xpath and css, but the span in which this CTA is included seems to be larger than the actual CTA.

I used the following import statements:

```
import helper.webdriver.ExtraMethods;
import helper.webdriver.JavascriptMethods;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
```

And my actual code for this was:

```
clickAndWait(resolve("xpath=(//*[@class='CTA btn_prim'])[1]"));
```

I also tried using the "tabindex" atribute, which has a specific index for each item.

Comment: try `java.awt.Robot`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have searched for this after reading your comment. I have found that I would need the following import statements:
    import java.awt.AWTException;
    import java.awt.Robot;
    import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
    import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

However, i cannot find the related commands for this specific action (clicking on text or on a certain location on the webpage).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Bit confused here - Is this query related to Selenium IDE? If so add the selenium-ide tag.

Comment: I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.6 . I'm not sure whether it is a Selenium IDE, as what I've found regarding this matter involves a firefox plugin. The IDE I use starts the browser on its own and can be used for other browsers as well. Should I still add the selenium-ide tag?

Answer (score 1):

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x, y);
r.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
r.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
```

this creates a robot, which moves the mouse cursor (the actual cursor. you shouldn't move your mouse) to the x/y position and performs a single left click.

x and y start at the top left of your screen.

This might not be the best solution if its any solution to this specific problem, as it can fuck it up pretty bad, but its working. if you know a better one feel free to tell me

Comment: I tried this solution and the actual result is that during the test, when this code is being computed, my pc just opens my start menu, instead of clicking on where the coordinates point. I took the x and y values from the WebDeveloper Tool from Firefox, using the ruler.

Comment: what is your screen resolution and what are your coordinates?

Comment: I use two monitors, both on 1920x1080. Can it be an issue related to having two monitors? I used the following coordinates: (904, 1416). I thought this command would be applied within the browser. If it does not, I believe I must have my script first scroll to the element in question, as it is not visible in the first instance.

Comment: robot only works, with what you can see on your screen. and if you compare your screen resolution and your coordinates, you will see that the y you want to navigate to is bigger than your y axis of your screen. if i am not mistaken you can also scroll with robot, but i am not sure how. also it starts so the x and y axis counting on your main monitor. assuming your left monitor is your main monitor, and both are horizontally adjusted, you have an effective screen resolution of 3840x1080 pixels

Comment: I would like to thank you for this method, I have managed to even scroll with it! I used the press action, then added a move coordinate, and then the release (all coordinates are located on the scrollbar, of course). Unfortunately, this method will need revising if there will ever be a resolution change, but that's very little effort. Again, thanks a million, and let me know if you want any details regarding the scroll event. Additionally, this is my first question on Stack Overflow and I'm not quite sure how to handle it now, that it's been resolved.

Comment: if this resolved your question, simply click the checkmark left of the answer to mark it as accepted and "close" the question